# What happens when one squares an ODE in general?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose one has a ODE of the form $(y^{'})^{\frac{1}{2}}=f(y,x)$. What happens if we square it? Are there any pitfalls?

Comment: i don't think so, because it is an elementary operation that does not require special treatment

Comment: Yes, $(y')^{1/2}=-y$ has no solutions, while $y'=y$ has $y=C\cdot exp$

Comment: @despaigne I do not understand the "while"? How you compare these two?

Comment: @arf Answering "in general " is difficult, depends on individual function. $ y'= -xy$ makes a bell curve turn upside down when there is a sign change in front.

Comment: @despaigne $\sqrt{y'} = -y$ has solutions $y = \frac{1}{c-x}$ when $x>c$

Comment: @Gribouillis There is a missing $\sqrt{}$ on the right hand side, Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one has
$$y' = f^2(y, x)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad (y')^{\frac{1}{2}} = |f(y, x)|$$
so the squared equation is equivalent to the first one in domains where $f(y, x)\ge 0$.

Comment: what about the complent of such domains? You know what happens there?

Comment: In a region where $f(y, x)<0$, the equation $(y')^{\frac{1}{2}}=f(y, x)$ is impossible because a square root cannot be negative, while $y' = f^2(x, y)$ can have solutions (and does have solutions if usual assumptions are satisfied).

Comment: oh so complex solutions dont help in that case?

Comment: This answer doesn't cover complex solutions. If $f$ is complex, the above equivalence doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that the Picard-Lindelof theorem still is true. This is the foundational tool for studying ordinary differential equations. It says that if you have an ODE of the form $$y' = f(x,y(x))$$ with some initial data, then this problem has a unique solution on a small time interval if $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$.

An important catch is that even if $f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz in $y$, $f^2$ may not be, so your ODE may not have a unique solution even locally.

Comment: I don't agree on this, because only local lipschitz property is needed. If $f$ is lipschitz in $y$ uniformly in $t$ on a compact domain, then $f^2$ is also lipschitz, because $|a^2 - b^2| = |a-b| .|a+b|$

Answer (score 0):

It matters, as the solution may be dramatically different. Consider the ODE

$y'-y=0$. We know this is first order linear with solution $y(t)=ce^{t}$. Suppose we changed it to $y'-y=cos(t)$. This has solution $y(t)=ce^t+\frac{sin(t)-cos(t)}{2}$. However, suppose we square the $y'$ term: $(y')^2+y'=cos(t)$. This actually changes the ODE from linear to non-linear, this does not have a closed form solution.

In general, squaring one or more terms of the ODE changes it from linear to non-linear, which are generally much harder to solve. Typically, we need numeric approximations to solve it.

Note the ODE is still linear if we had $y'-y=cos^2(t)$, as it becomes non-linear when we square the function we are interested in or its unknown derivatives.

Comment: Sorry for that but $(y')^2+y'=\cos(t)$ has  solutions ! But I totally agree with you. Cheers.